# SQL Inserts sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracale SQL Developer, and I am wondering when I insert data into a table, will the data cascade to another table that has the first tables primary key as a foreign key for example if I run

```
insert into DEPARTMENT values ('1', 'Karate');
```

Will the first value in Column 'DEPARTMENTID' also be inserted into the other table I.E 'TEACHER' or do I have to manually insert the value into the both tables.

Thanks

Comment: no, you cannot have one insert add data to two tables. it's not `insert into foo,bar values ...`, after all.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up! I just thought that it would cascade maybe :S

Comment: If there were more required (not null) information in the `teacher` table, how could it get it?  Always need to create the parent before the child when foreign keys are involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, inserts will not cascade. You'll have to insert data in parent table and then in child tables.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up! I will mark the answer as correct